# Cannot get the text color black to transition into white (fade from one into the other) - JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Basically I want to transition the words in the div 'clickToContinue' from black to white, so that it fades into the other color. First I tried (directions at: https://jqueryui.com/animate/):

```
$("#logoBarImage").click(function(){
$("#paddingDiv").animate({
height: "0",
},1000);

$("#clickToContinue").animate({
color: "#FFFFFF",
}, 1000);
});
```

But no effect (except for the shrinking of the padding). So instead of using animation, I used directions (https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) to get one class to transition into another (where the original class is 'clickToContinue' and the other is 'clicked' - of course the difference between the classes is a matter of color):

```
$("#logoBarImage").click(function(){
$("#paddingDiv").animate({
height: "0",
},1000);

$("#clickToContinue").toggleClass( "clicked", 1000, "linear" );
});
```

But still no transition, although paddingDiv still shrinks fine. The word just stays black.

Here are what I think the relevant parts of the code are that might be causing the problem; please fix so that the black may transition into white:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" contents="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<style>

#clickToContinue {
text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #E5E5E5;
color: black;  
}

.clicked {
color: white;  
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="paddingDiv"> </div>

<div id="logoBarImage"><img src=""/></div>

<div id="clickToContinue">
<p>(please click on the logo to continue)</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done just using CSS3:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVMbWB

**here is CSS:**

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
div{
  float: left;
}
div#pagewrapper{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40em;
}
div#logoBarImage{
  margin: 1% 5%;
  width: 10%;
}
div#logoBarImage img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
div#clickToContinue{
  width: 20%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #333;
}
div#clickToContinue:hover{
 transition: background 0.5s ;
  background: #333;
  transition: color 0.8s;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**and HTML:**

```
<div id='pagewrapper'>
<div id="paddingDiv"> </div>

<div id="logoBarImage"><img src="http://million-wallpapers.ru/wallpapers/1/7/16727657681030058500/poligon-t-90-tank.jpg"/>
  </div>

<div id="clickToContinue">
<p>(please click on the logo to continue)</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

and if you need to use Jquery plugin "color", then it looks like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpbNyN

Comment: I think it has something to do with the links. I certainly do not think I have <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> on my computer.

Comment: well, the relative link doesn't mean that it is something that is on your computer: relative link mean that resource is taken from the local directory relatively to the file, where this link is provided, so, if this is on the hosting platform of, let's say, "somesite.com", then the link "/resources/demos/style.css" will be read as http://somesite.com/resources/demos/style.css